# Python How to click on auto complete in selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, selenium

*I am trying to click on a auto complete search bar results on the website https://homely.com.au so i can search for the resulats*

***i want to click on the drop down element that appears after the pasting of the city name so i can search with the full city name and get the results***

**here is the search bar code of the website**

```
<div class="SearchAutoComplete SearchAutoComplete--isDropdown SearchAutoComplete--hasIcon">
    <div class="SearchAutoComplete-searchIcon">
        <span role="presentation" class="icon-wrapper">
            <svg class="icon icon-search">
                <use
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-search">
                </use>
            </svg>
        </span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="SearchAutoComplete-input" placeholder="Search by agent name or suburb" value="Aberdare">
        <div class="SearchAutoComplete-clear animated fadeIn">
            <span role="presentation" class="icon-wrapper">
                <svg class="icon icon-close">
                    <use
                        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-close">
                    </use>
                </svg>
            </span>
        </div>
        <ul class="SearchAutoComplete-results hide">
            <li class="heading">
                <span role="presentation" class="icon-wrapper">
                    <svg class="icon icon-map">
                        <use
                            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-map">
                        </use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                <span class="heading-text">locations</span>
            </li>
            <li data-field-index="0" data-index="0" class="SearchAutoComplete-item active">
                <a>Yabbra, New South Wales</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**here is the inspect element of the search bar and the results if that helps**

[image]

**AND THE RESULTS INSPECT ELEMENT**

[image]

***and here is my selenium code***

```
    driver.get('https://homely.com.au/')
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Agent Finder')]"))).click()
    try:
        wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'No thanks')]"))).click()
    except:
        pass
#THE PROBLEM STARTS FROM HERE
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.SearchAutoComplete-input'))).clear()
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.SearchAutoComplete-input'))).send_keys(tiki)
    time.sleep(1)
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.SearchAutoComplete-input'))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.SearchAutoComplete-input'))).click()
    time.sleep(1)
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.SearchAutoComplete-input'))).send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
    time.sleep(1)
    wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.SearchAutoComplete-input'))).send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Start comparing agents')]"))).click()
    except:
        pass
```

***i am trying to input a city name and click on it (cause otherwise search won't show) and then click on the field once again press down arrow and then press enter***

here is the page 
[image]

how i click on the auto complete search bar

and then this page comes with result

[image]

**but the problem is my solution is inconsistent and search sometimes works sometimes doesn't
any better robust way to do this with selenium ?**

Comment: So what do you want to achieve in the end again,

Comment: i want to click on the drop down element that appears after the pasting of the city name so i can search with the full city name and get the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.homely.com.au/agents')

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "//input[starts-with(@class, 'SearchAutoComplete-input')]")
search.clear()
search.send_keys('ge')
auto_complete = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//li[starts-with(@class, 'SearchAutoComplete-item')]")
auto_complete[0].click()
```

Just comment so I can fix the code more to suit your needs

Comment: i used your code as reference and tweaked it a bit and fixed the issue thanks for the help

Comment: Glad i can helped

Comment: I sometime encounter cases where selenium throws back something like `element is not visible` or `element is not clickable`, it can be fixed by just find that element again and click it. try to use `time.sleep(2)` in some cases helped too.

Comment: or using the wait method